# youtube API получение рефреш токена

Tags: php, youtube-api

исползую [сдк](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) Гугл и вот фрагмент кода

```
$this->client = new Google_Client();
    $this->client->setAuthConfigFile('client.json');
    $this->client->addScope([
        Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBE,
        Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBE_FORCE_SSL,
        Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBE_READONLY,
        Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBEPARTNER_CHANNEL_AUDIT,
        Google_Service_Plus::USERINFO_EMAIL,
        Google_Service_Plus::USERINFO_PROFILE,
        Google_Service_Plus::PLUS_LOGIN
    ]);
    $this->client->setAccessType('offline');
    $this->client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .       $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

получаю все кроме рефреш токена, как получить рефреш токен?